# PHP FFI - Failed resolving C function

Tags: php, ffi

I'm messing around with FFI in PHP 8.1 and I cannot call my function loaded from my so library.

**get_int.h**:

```
#define FFI_SCOPE "GETINT"
#define FFI_LIB "./getint.so"

int getint(int val);
```

**get_int.c**:

```
#include "./get_int.h"

int getint(int val)
{
    return val;
}
```

**index.php**:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

$ffi = \FFI::cdef(
    file_get_contents('/srv/www/myapp/libs/get_int.h'),
    "/srv/www/myapp/libs/getint.so"
);

$ffi->getint(123);
```

I compile it with: `gcc -shared -o getint.so -fPIC get_int.c`.

New file is created: `/srv/www/myapp/libs/getint.so`.

When I run index.php it says that:

> Fatal error: Uncaught FFI\Exception: Failed resolving C function 'getint' in /srv/www/myapp/public/index.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /srv/www/myapp/public/index.php(7): FFI::cdef('#define FFI_SCO...', '/srv/www/myapp...') #1 {main} thrown in /srv/www/myapp/public/index.php on line 7

Comment: Few days later I just restarted docker and started my application and it suddenly worked :|
If somebody can tell me anything about why I had this problem please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the following lines from your header file:

```c
#define FFI_SCOPE "GETINT"
#define FFI_LIB "./getint.so"
```

You are trying to define the .so library in your header but you don't use this library in your code. The code is actually defining the library. So that's "confusing" the FFI extension.

Also, you don't need to define a scope for this scenario.